Expected number of tosses of a fair coin to see HTH?
Question as in title
I get the solution below apart from the bold term:
Let $x$ be the expected value of the number of tosses to see HTH at the start of the game. There is a $\frac{1}{2}$ probability the toss is a $T$ and you start over with a new expected value of $x + 1$. There is a $\frac{1}{4}$ probability you get HH and then start over with a new expected value of $x$. There is a $\frac{1}{8}$ probability you get an HTT and then start over with a new expected value of $x + 3$. There is a $\frac{1}{8}$ probability that you get HTH and end the game. Thus:
$$
x = \frac{1}{2}(x + 1) + \frac{1}{4}(x) + \frac{1}{8}(x + 3) + \frac{1}{8}(3)
$$
Solving for $x$, we find that $x = 10$.
My question: Why is this true if we take $x$ as the expected number of rolls to get $HTH$. Shouldn't it be 'the expected number of rolls given we got a head' instead of 'the expected number of rolls given we haven't got anything'? I think what they have done is $x+2 -2$ i.e. starting from heads has saved us 2 rolls but why is this the case?

Yes, that is confusing.  If you have tossed $HH$ you have still completed the first $H$.
Oddly, the answer is still correct.  I'll explain why it works at the end.
To do it properly, use states.  There are three active states, according to how much of the desired sequence you have running:  $\emptyset, H, HT$. For a state $S$, let $E_S$ denote the expected number of tosses it will take to finish.
We get relations out of the possible state transitions as:
$$E_{\emptyset}=\frac 12\times (E_H+1)+\frac 12\times (E_{\emptyset}+1)$$
$$E_H=\frac 12\times (E_H+1)+\frac 12\times (E_{HT}+1)$$
$$E_{HT}=\frac 12\times 1+\frac 12\times (E_{\emptyset}+1)$$
which is easily solved to yield $E_{\emptyset}=10$, confirming the incomplete computation.
The incomplete computation works for the following reason:  Their $x$ is meant to be the same as my $E_{\emptyset}$.  They are correct in each case except the $HH$ case.  In that one, they should have $E_H+2$.   Now, look at the first equation I wrote.  Multiplying that by $2$ tells us that $2E_{\emptyset}=2+E_H+E_{\emptyset}$ which implies that $E_{\emptyset}=E_H+2$.  So they are correct that you can substitute $x$ there.  To be sure, I don't see why that should be obvious...seems to me you have to write out the state argument or something equivalent to it.  In any case, some explanation is required.
